# Populate dropdownlist with data from sitecore to edit the item

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore

Sorry for long description but it is necessary to describe my problem. I have made a web form where the staff can edit their detail. E.g Address Details.

So The data for editing is shown to the user using following code.

```
<p>Address</p>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtBoxAdd"></asp:TextBox>
<p>City</p>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtBoxCity"></asp:TextBox>
<p>Country</p>
 <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtBoxCountry"></asp:TextBox>
```

**BackEnd**.

```
txtBoxAdd.Text = addressItem["address"];
txtBoxCity.Text = addressItem["city"];
txtBoxCountry.Text = addressItem["country"];
```

When the user clicks on `Save` Button, the item is put in editing mode. `addressItem.Editing.BeginEdit();` And update the fields with the values in the text boxes.

Now The `addressItem` with the field `country`,  `addressItem["country"]` is a dropdown in sitecore. With source as (the template for the addressItem): 
[image]

**Is it possible that I show this drop down in the front end. filled with all the values from the sitecore.**

What I am thinking is to make a dropdown list and add in it all the children of item `/sitecore/content/Site Config/Constants/Countries`. But I guess there could be a better solution?

Comment: Why not use the Sitecore page editor? or should this work on cds?

Comment: It is a requirement not to use Page Editor.

Comment: @JanBluemink The reason is when using the Sitecore Page Editor, the page editor bar appear on top of page. Is there some why to hide this bar and still edit the items in page editor mode.

Comment: There probably isn't a much better solution given the direction you need to go with server controls. You're probably best served by populating the dropdown then storing the selected value in your save button handler. About the only improvement would be to read the source field off of the field item.

Comment: I don't think the solution is the page editor in this instance, it seems like the OP is storing data about users as Sitecore items, which then need to be editable from the front-end (CD instance) possibly from a profile page once the user has logged in.

Comment: @jammykam Yes I am storing data as sitecore items. And when the user is logged in then I made a profile page to change the data.

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore way: use Page(Experience) Editor. It is better to use this way, you'll get Sitecore benefits and development will be quicker and easier.

ASP.Net WebForms way: use DropDownList datasource. For example like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15205380/how-to-bind-a-drop-down-control-to-a-data-source-in-asp-net).

Comment: What about the bar that appears on top of page when I use the Page Editor, is it some how possible to hide it.

Comment: Sure, create specific role for this type of users and configure security access rights on items in Core database to hide what you need.