# Dropdownlist just retrieving objects and dynamically show in Ajax Text box

Tags: sql, asp.net, ajax, drop-down-menu, asp.net-ajax

So Im starting as a new ASP Developer (been using Java for a bit, but now project demands ASP), so bare a little with my ignorance :( .

What I am trying to do is create a dynamic dropdown list from a table I got in SQL SERVER and depending on what you choose on the list show the information on the txt editor (In theory shouldnt be so hard, but since I just started, it just does not seem so easy). I created the entity for it, the data for it and the bussiness logic for it and the interconnection (It is already reading and retrieving from the DB, but just a list). Here is, what I have doing so hard.

Entity.Messages

```
    public class Messages
    {
        public int id { get; set; }

        public string title { get; set; }

        public string subject { get; set; }
        public string body { get; set; }
        public string createdBy { get; set; }


        public Messages()
        {
            id = 0;
            title = "";
            subject = "";
            body = "";
            createdBy = "";
        }

        public Messages(int idMessages)
        {
            idMessages = id;
            title = "";
            subject = "";
            body = "";
            createdBy = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Data.Messages

```
public class Messages : Data
{

    public Messages() : base()
        {

        }

    public List<Entity.Messages> GetAll()
    {
        List<Entity.Messages> message = new List<Entity.Messages>();
        //SQL Command para llamar el stored procedure
        SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("dbo.[Messages_GetAll]", base.Db);
        //Ejecuta consulta
        DataTable dtItem = base.Execute(comando);
        //Transforma el Datatable en una lista de proyectos.
        foreach (DataRow dr in dtItem.Rows)
            message.Add(GetFromDataRow(dr));

        return message;
    }

    public Entity.Messages GetById(int id)
    {
        Entity.Messages m = new Entity.Messages();
        //SQL Command para llamar el stored procedure
        SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("dbo.[Messages_GetById]", base.Db);
        //parametros del store procedure
        SqlParameter spKey = new SqlParameter("@Id", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
        spKey.Value = id;
        comando.Parameters.Add(spKey);
        //Ejecuta consulta
        DataTable dt = base.Execute(comando);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            m = GetFromDataRow(dt.Rows[0]);
        return m;
    }

    private ASF.HC.JobApplication.Entity.Messages GetFromDataRow(DataRow dr)
    {
        Entity.Messages m = new Entity.Messages();
        m.id = dr["Id"] == DBNull.Value ? -1 : int.Parse(dr["Id"].ToString());
        m.title = dr["Title"] == DBNull.Value ? "" : dr["Title"].ToString();
        m.subject = dr["Subject"] == DBNull.Value ? "" : dr["Subject"].ToString();
        m.body = dr["Body"] == DBNull.Value ? "" : dr["Body"].ToString();
        m.createdBy = dr["createdBy"] == DBNull.Value ? "" : dr["createdBy"].ToString();
        return m;
    }
}
```

BO.Messages

```
public class Messages
    {

        public Entity.Messages GetByID(int id)
        {
            Data.Messages oMessage = new Data.Messages();
            return oMessage.GetById(id);
        }
        public List<Entity.Messages> GetAll()
        {
            Data.Messages oMessage = new Data.Messages();
            return oMessage.GetAll();
        }
```

And where Im trying to display it, I see the DropDownList and well I see the List with the objects, but I want to display is the title.

MEssage.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Messages.aspx.cs" Inherits="ASF.HC.JobApplication.Admin.Messages" %>
<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="ajaxToolkit" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2>Messages</h2>    
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager2" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <legend>Pick the template to use:</legend>
    <asp:dropdownlist id ="ddlTemplate" runat ="server" Height="38px" Width="397px">
                  <asp:listitem value ="1"> Juan Valdez </asp:listitem >
                  <asp:listitem Value ="2"> Querido bebe</asp:listitem>
                  </asp:dropdownlist >     
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <asp:TextBox ID ="txtDetails" runat="server" Width="600px" Height="300px" Visible="true" ></asp:TextBox>
            <ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender ID="TextBox1_HtmlEditorExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtDetails" 
                EnableSanitization="false" DisplaySourceTab="true" >
            </ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender>
</asp:Content>
```

Messages.aspx.cs

```
    public partial class Messages : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            loadList();
        }

        public void loadList()
        {
            BO.Messages template = new BO.Messages();
            ddlTemplate.DataSource = template.GetAll();
            ddlTemplate.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Im trying to go step by step, but first I wanna see the value and not the objects, and according to what I choose to see the Body field Displayed on the text field on Ajax. But first, and most importantly, show the title field on the dropdownlist :(

**EDIT: So I got to show the Title instead of all the object. But now, do you guys know any way to as soon as I choose the title, to have it displayed on the Text from ajax? Like dynamically? Any point would be greatly appreciated.**

Any help or pointer would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you need set the datavalue field and the datatext field.  This looks like a good place to start:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15205380/how-to-bind-a-drop-down-control-to-a-data-source-in-asp-net

Comment: Thanks man. But I thought they were set on the entity and thus, should be accesible right?

Comment: You need to tell the dropdown list control what fields in the entity it needs bind to.  Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, all I needed was to map the datavalue and datatext field.